# Selenium and Python: Trouble with clicking a button with "data-disable-with" attribute

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

[edit: added screenshot of Chrome developer view below...]

I'm trying to click on this object:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Load Report" class="button" data-disable-with="Load Report">
```

In the UI, the button is clickable until it gets clicked to start the report.  It is then disabled until the report loads.

But when I make the call in code:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("commit").click()
```

it throws an exception:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615355 (d5698f682d8b2742017df6c81e0bd8e6a3063189),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.0 x86_64)
```

So, Im pretty sure I found the right button (unless there is another one named "commit"), but for some reason it is not clickable.  There are no discernible objects in front of it, but maybe something hiding in the CSS or ...?  I'm a know-nothing-noob.  Any hints?

[image: my puzzle]

Comment: @PedroLobito If the element were in a different frame, it would have thrown an `ElementNotFoundException`.

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait for clickable? It's possible that the element is getting clicked before the report loads or some other action needs to complete. Another possibility is that `INPUT` element never becomes visible and you need to find the visible element to interact with. It's hard to say without a link to the page

Comment: @JeffC thanks for your comments.  sadly it's a financial system that's locked down behind passwords, so i can't share.  i'll have to try to get to the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a *dynamic* element so to invoke `click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.button[name='commit'][value='Load Report']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='button' and @name='commit'][@value='Load Report']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Please see the answer I've now posted to your question. :not(style) doesn't (or shouldn't) do what you think it does (or what it actually does).

Comment: Thanks, I am going through each and every details you have provided within the answer.

Comment: So both the XPATH and the CSS approaches worked - Thanks!   But if a 'wait' was involved, why couldn't I just pause the program for a few seconds, and then move forward?  I think 'wait' is more subtle than that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explicit wait to element to be visible

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("URL");
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 WebElement commitBtn = driver.findElement(By.name("commit"));
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(commitBtn));
 commitBtn.click();
```

or you can use javascriptexecurtor

```
WebElement commitBtn = driver.findElement(By.name("commit"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(commitBtn));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", commitBtn );
```

Comment: thanks.  but this code is all javascript.  how can i do this in python?  what don't i understand?

Comment: You can find similar code in python also. As I have not too much expertise on that. In python, also JavascriptExecutor interface is there. Only some syntax is changed